# How can I @link something that isn't imported?

Tags: typescript

TypeScript [recently introduced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-3/#jsdoc-link-tags) the `@link` tag in JSDoc comments. The [documentation is here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#link).

However, `@link` only generates an actual link if the TypeScript compiler knows the link target. In other words, whatever I link to must either be declared within the same file or imported. This isn't always the case, however. Take this (made-up) example:

*wheel.ts*

```
/** A wheel for use with a {@link Car}. */
export interface Wheel {
  // ...
}
```

In this example, the JSDoc comment in *wheel.ts* references a type `Car` that is defined in a separate file, *car.ts*. Because *wheel.ts* doesn't import *car.ts*, TypeScript doesn't know what `@link Car` points to. As a result, it can't display a proper link for `Car` when displaying the documentation in VS Code:

[image: screenshot]

So my question is: **How can I tell TypeScript where to find the definition of `Car`?**

I've tried the following approaches:

**1. Regular import**

Adding `import { Car } from './car';` to the top of *wheel.ts* solves the problem and creates an actual link to `Car` (note how "Car" has turned blue now):

[image]

However, it leads to the TypeScript error *"'Car' is declared but its value is never read. (6133)"* on the import line. TypeScript doesn't seem to consider the `@link` tag an actual usage of the imported type.

I can add `// @ts-ignore` above the import to tell TypeScript to ignore the error. But that seems pretty ugly to me.

**2. Type import**

Instead of a regular import, I can use a type import: `import type { Car } from './car';`. The result is the same: The link works, but I get a TypeScript error.

**3. Inline import**

TypeScript supports [type imports within JSDoc comments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#import-types). So I tried the following syntax:

```
/** A wheel for use with a {@link import("./car").Car}. */
```

However, it seems that TypeScript doesn't evaluate imports within links:

[image]

**4. Typedef comment**

I tried importing the type as follows:

```
/** @typedef {import('./car').Car} Car */

/** A wheel for use with a {@link Car}. */
export interface Wheel {
  // ...
}
```

However, this didn't create a link, either.

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. The behavior you're describing sounds like a bug in new functionality.

Comment: @Ouroborus Thanks for the differentiation. I've created an issue with TypeScript: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47558

Comment: I realize your example is contrived, but there is nothing in the interface that is forcing a `Wheel` to be used with a `Car`. As such, your linking to `Car` seems spurious.

Comment: @djs thank you for your feedback! There are situations where one would still be interested in referring in docs to a module that is not part of neighbouring code. E.g. if we use a similar technique / for a Todo / etc.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with VS. `{@link import("./car").Car}` works nicely in WebStorm

Comment: @undefined Have you tried in VSCode? It is supposed to be fixed in TS since then.

Comment: Has their been resolution to this? I still am unable to get this to work. I've tried your four potential solutions. TS 5.0.0.

Comment: @ElijahMock as for me I now regularly use options 1 and 2. Please feel free to open a new question with a [mcve] if you need help.

Answer (score 1):

This question has an answer nowadays.

To quote the [TSDOC documentation](https://tsdoc.org/pages/tags/link/):

```
 * Suppose the `Button` class is part of an external package.  In that case, we
 * can include the package name when referring to it:
 *
 * {@link my-control-library#Button | the Button class}
 *
 * The package name can include an NPM scope and import path:
 *
 * {@link @microsoft/my-control-library/lib/Button#Button | the Button class}
```

Comment: Your answer applies to TSDoc. My question was about the behavior of the TypeScript compiler, for instance within VS Code. Unfortunately, the two aren't exactly identical. However, the underlying problem has since been fixed in TypeScript. Nowadays, TS doesn't consider an import superfluous if it is needed for a link.